# How to rename a file with a : on a MacBook?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, hard-drive, filenames

I'm accessing a Windows HDD from my MacBook (local network). The HDD has a file with a : in it, which is not a valid character on both Windows and Mac. I wanted to rename the file from my Mac since it seems impossible from Windows but to no avail. The : is replaced by a backslash but the file throws an error when I try to modify it. Is there a way other than rely on a Linux computer?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character? if you are doing `touch :` try with `touch \:`. Another option is to use **TAB** after `touch ./` to try and see if it completes the filename or gives any hint. May be also interesting to list the directory and see if you have permissions to edit with `ls -la`. Also, check if you have a literal colon **:** or a fullwidth 
colon **：**. Send feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rename it via the command line without doing anything special - this at least works on an APFS volume, but perhaps your Windows volume will work differently.

These commands worked as expected:

```
touch : 
mv : a
```

Comment: In your case it seems to work. However I can't make it work if the file also has a space. Can you rename a file such as `touch "Test: New"`?

Comment: Nevermind, I just made it work for my Mac (local file). However it doesn't appear to work on my remote HDD. :(

Comment: @EdgarDerby OK - I was about to tell you the same - that it works locally. What is the nature of the remote connection? Is it an SMB or NFS share?

Comment: SMB. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: Did you try what @MrJavy wrote as a comment above? The tab autocomplete is worth a shot, though it seems that the issue really lies on the Windows machine rather than the Mac...

Comment: That works in the sense that the TAB does autocomplete correctly. However, the operation is still unsuccessful. It says: "mv: rename Test: Example to Test Example: No such file or directory".

Comment: @EdgarDerby Can you try using a wildcard?

`mv Test* renamed_file`

Comment: Exactly the same error. :(

Comment: @EdgarDerby Going back to the Windows machine, you may be able to rename the file via the bash subsystem (if installed) rather than Windows itself. I was just able to do this. Maybe this will work?

Comment: This seems promising! I found [this resource](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/enable-linux-subsystem-install-ubuntu-windows-10/), let me give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately this failed too. More or less the same error "mv: cannot stat 'Naruto: Shippuden': No such file or directory".

Comment: @EdgarDerby Are you able to read the file (might also depend on what type of file this is)? I’m thinking that if you can read it, perhaps you can open it and save it as a new file. Then maybe you can move all other files from the folder it is in, and delete the containing folder.